# Groovy: How to fetch the particular list of values from json output

Tags: json, shell, curl, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to get a list of values from the Json output.

**MY CODE :**

```
def VALUES_BEFORE = sh """
                   curl -X POST "http://node-01.xyz.com:32010/abc/def" \\
                   -H "accept: application/json" \\
                   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \\
                   -d '{ "cell_ids": [${payload}] }' | json_pp
                  """
def json = readJSON text: VALUES_BEFORE 
                    def mylist = json .value
                 echo "Values are ${mylist}"
```

**Output is below JSON :**

```
[
   {
      "def" : "bins",
      "value" : 294
   },
   {
      "def" : "valid_bins",
      "value" : 294
   },
   {
      "def" : "covered_bins",
      "value" : 1
   },
   {
      "def" : "sum",
      "value" : 415
   },
   {
      "def" : "histro",
      "value" : "-130.0 -> -120.0: 129 | -120.0 -> -110.0: 82 | -110.0 -> -100.0: 20 | -100.0 -> -90.0: 1 | -90.0 -> -80.0: 0 | -80.0 -> -70.0: 0 | -70.0 -> -60.0: 0 | -60.0 -> -50.0: 0"
   }
]
```

**Expected result :**

```
"value" : "-130.0 -> -120.0: 129 | -120.0 -> -110.0: 82 | -110.0 -> -100.0: 20 | -100.0 -> -90.0: 1 | -90.0 -> -80.0: 0 | -80.0 -> -70.0: 0 | -70.0 -> -60.0: 0 | -60.0 -> -50.0: 0"
```

Your help would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried ? Please update your question with the code you tried to parse the output and how it fails.

Comment: @ou_ryperd I have updated the code and trying to parse the output, I have given expected parse output in question.

Comment: So you want to find the object with a `def` property of “histro” and extract the `value` property of that object?

Comment: @DaveNewton exactly, Yes

Comment: What is the problem(s) preventing you from doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially a straight-forward one-liner, using `findResult`:

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText '''\
[
   {
      "def" : "bins",
      "value" : 294
   },
   {
      "def" : "valid_bins",
      "value" : 294
   },
   {
      "def" : "covered_bins",
      "value" : 1
   },
   {
      "def" : "sum",
      "value" : 415
   },
   {
      "def" : "histro",
      "value" : "-130.0 -> -120.0: 129 | -120.0 -> -110.0: 82 | -110.0 -> -100.0: 20 | -100.0 -> -90.0: 1 | -90.0 -> -80.0: 0 | -80.0 -> -70.0: 0 | -70.0 -> -60.0: 0 | -60.0 -> -50.0: 0"
   }
]'''

String result = json.findResult{ 'histro' == it.def ? it.value : null }

assert result == '-130.0 -> -120.0: 129 | -120.0 -> -110.0: 82 | -110.0 -> -100.0: 20 | -100.0 -> -90.0: 1 | -90.0 -> -80.0: 0 | -80.0 -> -70.0: 0 | -70.0 -> -60.0: 0 | -60.0 -> -50.0: 0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here some more simpler approaches of the previous answer:

**Variant 1**

```
def mylist = json.find { it.def == "histro" }.value
```

**Variant 2**

```
def mylist2 = json.collect { [(it.def):it.value] }.histro
```

This converts the json output to a map having `def` as the key and `value` as the value. Then to access any entry use the map directly.